# MITMProxy exits after some time

Tags: mitmproxy

I am using MITMProxy on my mac to proxy my android app network calls.

Details of my environment
Mitmproxy: 10.1.5 binary
Python:    3.12.0
OpenSSL:   OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023
Platform:  macOS-13.6-x86_64-i386-64bit

I have installed mitmproxy certificate on the android device and I have added proxy details in the device wifi settings.

I start mitmproxy and i start seeing network flows listed but after some time it exits automatically.

observation: after mitmproxy exits terminal goes in strange state. mouse click on terminal prints some character like - 65;78;36M65;7836M65;78

I have to reset the terminal to come out of that state.

I don't get any error, even if i print the error stream i dont get anything there. Sometimes when i try to exit this state by ctrl+c then i get this error

[image: mitmproxy error]

Comment: Please do not post terminal output as (incomplete) screenshot. Anyway this looks more like a bug in mitmproxy, so you can search on https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues if it is an already known bug (your output misses the relevant information so I can not say if it is a known problem) and if not yet known add a new issue.

Comment: @Rishi I am also suffering from this problem. Have you found a solution or a reason?